# Pass multiple parameters to function by pipeline

Tags: powershell, function, parameters, pipeline

I'm having trouble passing two parameters via pipeline to a function.

```
function Test{
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
[parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
[string]$jeden,
[parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
[string]$dwa
)
Process{write-host "$jeden PLUS $dwa"}
}

"one", "two"|Test
```

What I expected as an outcome was

```
one PLUS two
```

but what I got was

```
one PLUS one
two PLUS two
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, since both parameters get used twice. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by creating `pscustomobject` and piping it to function, where `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` property is set to true for both parameters.

```
function Test{
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
[parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
[string]$jeden,
[parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
[string]$dwa
)
Process{write-host "$jeden PLUS $dwa"}
}

$Params = [pscustomobject]@{
    jeden = “Hello”
    dwa = “There”
}

$Params |Test
```

OUTPUT:

`Hello PLUS There`

Variable assigning can be skipped and `[pscustomobject]` can be piped directly.

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried to pass both strings as single object? Seems its ur pipeline is treating dem as 2 obj...

```
@("one", "two") | Test
```

EDIT. Try to define test in order to accept array:

```
function Test {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [string[]]$strings
    )
    Process {
        write-host "$($strings[0]) PLUS $($strings[1])"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and the result is the same

Comment: maybe you can try to define your Test function to accept an array and then use the pipeline to pass the array of strings. Check my edited comment and try it

Comment: With the edited code the outcome is different but not what I need

    `one PLUS` 
    `two PLUS`